# does Postgres string functions (including regexp_*) consider tab as spaces?

Tags: postgresql

I am running some SQL over a Postgres Server 9.5

a field got sometimes has leading spaces, including literal white space, and tab spaces '\t'

in many programming languages it's easy to do with a regexp replace, like this in JavaScript:

```
> '   \tafsdfwef\t  \n'.replace(/\s+/g, '')
'afsdfwef'
```

then I found PostgreSQL also has this `regexp_replace` function and it also support `\s` to mean `[[:space:]]`

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

but this `\s` seems only recognizing literally white spaces `' '` ?  the question is does this PostgreSQL regex support `\s` to include all kinds of spaces ( tabs, newlines )?

```
db=> SELECT regexp_replace('\tafsdfwef', '\s+', '');
 regexp_replace 
----------------
 \tafsdfwef
(1 row)

db=> SELECT regexp_matches('\tafsdfwef', '\s+');
 regexp_matches 
----------------
(0 rows)
```

then I tested if `trim` function can recognize the other spaces? seems also no?

```
db=> SELECT trim('\tafsdfwef\t');
    btrim     
--------------
 \tafsdfwef\t
(1 row)

db=> SELECT trim('   \tafsdfwef\t');
    btrim     
--------------
 \tafsdfwef\t
(1 row)

db=> SELECT trim('   \tafsdfwef\t  \n   ');
      btrim       
------------------
 \tafsdfwef\t  \n
(1 row)
```

So, does PostgreSQL have an easy function can do strip all kinds of spaces, in leading, in middle, and at tail of a string?

EDIT: My complain is also toward the PostgreSQL documentation, they mentioned `\t` to `[:space:]` but isn't really all kinds of spaces, as most programmers know,  it mentioned POSIX regex but isn't really POSIX,

anyone knows a better place to file them a bug ?

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

EDIT: here is Mozilla JavaScript documentation, what `\s` means
`a single white space character, including space, tab, form feed, line feed and other Unicode spaces. Equivalent to [ \f\n\r\t\v\u00a0\u1680\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff].`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: `'    \tafsdfwef\t  \n   '` is a string with four spaces followed by a backslash character `\ ` followed by the character `t` followed by the character `a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Postgres regexp functions do consider tab as space. Actually the text `'\tafsdfwef'` does **not** contain tab character. You have to write the letter E (upper or lower case) just before the opening single quote to get tab char (and/or other *escape* chars) in it:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(E'\ta\nb\fc\rd', '\s', '', 'g')

 regexp_replace 
----------------
 abcd
(1 row)
```

Read about [string constants](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) in the documentation.